# How to list groups that host is member of?

Tags: ansible

I have a very complex Ansible setup with thousands of servers and hundreds of groups various servers are member of (dynamic inventory file).

Is there any way to easily display all groups that a specific host is member of?

I know how to list all groups and their members:

```
ansible localhost -m debug -a 'var=groups'
```

But I want to do this not for ALL hosts, but only for a single one.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Create a playbook called 'showgroups' (executable file) containing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ansible-playbook

- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: show the groups the host(s) are in
    debug:
      msg: "{{group_names}}"
```

You can run it like this to show the groups of one particular host (-l) in your inventory (-i):

```
 ./showgroups -i develop -l jessie.fritz.box
```

Comment: With apologies for the aside, I just wanted to admire the use of the shebang to turn a playbook into an executable. That's pretty.

Comment: FYI, if host is not present under a group, it lists "ungrouped". If host is also present under a group, it lists only the group name and not "ungrouped".

Comment: Ad hoc style: `ansible -m debug -a 'msg={{group_names}}' jessie.fritz.box`

Answer (score 29):

There is `group_names` [magic variable](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts):

> Additionally, `group_names` is a list (array) of all the groups the current host is in. This can be used in templates using Jinja2 syntax to make template source files that vary based on the group membership (or role) of the host

Comment: so you can use this command: `ansible ${hostname} -m debug -a var=group_names`

Comment: this comment just above should be accepted solution :)

Answer (score -4):

cat /etc/ansible/hosts | grep -e  [[]  && ansible all --list-hosts

Comment: This is totally incomplete. It assumes the only source of inventory is `/etc/ansible/hosts` and will only works if it's store as ini format.